# Map OPC UA server variable to IO port

Tags: gpio

I am running this code in a Raspberry Pi to run an OPC UA server and expose 1 variable: 'Status'

```
from opcua import Server
from random import randint
from opcua import Server
from random import randint
import datetime
import time

server = Server()
url = "opc.tcp://localhost:4840"
server.set_endpoint(url)

name = "OPCUA_SIMULATION_SERVER"
addspace = server.register_namespace(name)

node = server.get_objects_node()

Param = node.add_object(addspace, "Parameters")

Status = Param.add_variable(addspace, "Status", 0)
Status.set_writable()

server.start()
print("Server started at {}".format(url))from opcua import Server
```

My ultimate goal is to set 1 or 0 the Status based in a input coming from the IO port. Maybe by bridging a pin pair.

How can I map this 'Status' to the IO port, so for example when I bridge the pins I can set the Status variable to 1 and when the pins are not bridged, I can detect it and set the status to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be how to read a GPIO pin.

There must be hundreds of examples for different libraries.

One of the simplest is [Button](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/v1.6.2/recipes.html#button)

The following uses GPIO 2, but you could substitute any GPIO.

```
from gpiozero import Button

button = Button(2)

while True:
    if button.is_pressed:
        print("Button is pressed")
    else:
        print("Button is not pressed")
```

You could get value with:-
`Button.value`
Returns 1 if the button is currently pressed, and 0 if it is not